# iScroll parallax effect

Tags: javascript, parallax, iscroll

I'm trying to understand how parallax works with **iscroll5**. From what I understand, I can define a container as an indicator to alter scroll speed. However what I need to do is to apply a speed ratio to several elements at the same time.

Let's take the example below, how would I proceed to change the `speedratioX` of all `h2` elements at once?

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjh33oou/) (might be easier) and below the same example in SO :

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('iscroll__wrapper')[0],
    myScroll = new IScroll(container, { 
      scrollX: true, 
      scrollY: false, 
      mouseWheel: true
    });
```

```css
.iscroll__wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  list-style: none;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iscroll/build/iscroll-probe.js"></script>
<div class="iscroll__wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/200"></figure>
      <h2 class="title">Title 1</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/200"></figure>
      <h2 class="title">Title 1</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/200"></figure>
      <h2 class="title">Title 1</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Now, my questions are :**

- Is it possible to do it with iScroll only? And if so, how (the documentation only mentions altering the speed ratio of a whole container)?
- If it's not possible, I'm open to any other suggestions that can be integrated with iScroll and that don't require jQuery.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution. I'm posting this here as an answer in case it could help someone.

So I've noticed that **you can pass an array of `indicators`** and not just one element. So I've used a `for` loop to populate an array that I use when creating a new IScroll class.

Here is how it looks:

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('iscroll__wrapper')[0],
  containerLis = container.getElementsByTagName('li'),
  indicatorsArr = [],
  myScroll;

// Generating the indicators array
for (var i = 0; i < containerLis.length; i++) {
  var indicatorEl = container.getElementsByTagName('h2')[i];

  indicatorsArr[i] = {
    el: indicatorEl,
    resize: false,
    ignoreBoundaries: true,
    listenX: true,
    listenY: false,
    speedRatioX: 0.3
  };
}

// Creating a new IScroll class
myScroll = new IScroll(container, {
  scrollX: true,
  scrollY: false,
  mouseWheel: true,
  indicators: indicatorsArr
});
```

```css
.iscroll__wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  list-style: none;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h2 {
  padding-left: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iscroll/build/iscroll.js"></script>
<div class="iscroll__wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/200"></figure>
      <h2><span>Title 1</span></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/200"></figure>
      <h2><span>Title 2</span></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/200"></figure>
      <h2><span>Title 3</span></h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```